# Bigcommerce SideProductsRelated snippet

Tags: bigcommerce

I am editing product template on my Bigcommerce website and i am stuck at related products section.

Panel called "SideProductRelated.html" (inside Panels directory) is in charge for that section but the items themselves are being pulled by "%%SNIPPET_SideProductsRelated%%".
Aka, the code looks like this:

```
<div class="Block SideRelatedProducts Moveable Panel" style="display:%%GLOBAL_HideRelatedProductsPanel%%" id="SideProductRelated">
    <h2>%%LNG_RelatedProducts%%</h2>
    <div class="BlockContent">
        <ul class="ProductList">
            %%SNIPPET_SideProductsRelated%% <-- this is calling the items
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

But, i searched and searched, and i cant find that snippet anywhere...

Anybody knows where that little dude hidden himself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Even though the Panel SideProductRelated calls for %%SNIPPET_SideProductsRelated%%, you are looking for the SideRelatedProducts snippet which would be found in Snippets/SideRelatedProducts.html.